# How can I insert a Date attribute in Mysql DB using Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

please I need your help, I have been trying to add a Date field into DB using SpringBoot and JPA, but when I try to do it inserts the data in null, I mean, all other fields are recognized well using Json, but Date field in null. I have found other questions about it but I have not been able to solve it yet. I also tryied changing anotation above Date field and no luck. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

From my Entity "Member"

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "birth_day")
private Date birth_day;
```

From my controller

```
@PostMapping()
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<Member> save(@Validated @RequestBody Member input) {
    memberRepository.save(input);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(input);
}
```

This is the Json I create and pass through the body

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "last_name": "test",
    "phone": "test",
    "birth_day": "1991-04-05",
    "home_address": "test"
}
```

And this is the response I get

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "test",
    "last_name": "test",
    "phone": "test",
    "birth_day": null,
    "home_address": "test"
 }
```

For what I can see, the rest of the fields created with no problem, but the field birth_day is a null DateTime in DB.

By the way I am using Mysql 5.7.22 and Java 11

Comment: `Date` is a broken, deprecated class. Use classes from the `java.time` package, like `LocalDate`, instead.

Comment: Ok I changed Date to LocalDate, but still it keeps inserting null data to the field birth_date

Comment: did you also tried @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-DD") ?

Comment: That's what I used before and also no luck

Comment: I mean with uppercase DD.

Comment: yes, I noticed the uppercase and it was the same result

Comment: try using @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"), from https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat

Comment: Yep, that worked! I followed that tutorial in that link and all is working well now, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@JsonFormat` for `Date`s annotation needs also the `shape` parameter as shown [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat). So the snippet to use is

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "birth_day")
private Date birth_day;
```